# Framework7 change dialog button text (e.g. for translation)

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I'm using Framework7 for building a mobile app. This app should have the option to change the language. For that, I'm using an object with a key for the language that contains an object with keys to identify text and the text to insert. It looks like this:

```
var translations = {
  "en": {
    "btn-confirm": "Confirm",
    "btn-decline": "Decline"
  },
  "de": {
    "btn-confirm": "Bestätigen",
    "btn-decline": "Abbrechen"
  }
};
```

I've created a dialog like this:

```
var dialog_appReset = app.dialog.create({
  title: 'Warning!',
  text: 'You are resetting the app. Are you sure?',
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Confirm',
      onClick: function() {
        console.log('confirmed');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Decline',
      onClick: function() {
        console.log('declined');
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Now I want to change the content of the dialog when the language changes. For this I'm getting the translation for the item for the selected language and want to replace the text.

There are [methods for changing the title and the text](https://v3.framework7.io/docs/dialog.html#dialog-methods-properties) of the dialog, but not for the button texts.

So I tried to change the button texts like this: `dialog_appReset.buttons[0].text = 'Bestätigen'`, what changes the content, but doesn't update the dialog.

After some trying, I got a solution to update the button texts, but that's not very pretty:

1. Get actual dialog params 
   `var tempDialogParams = dialog_appReset.params;`
2. Update these params 
   `tempDialogParams.buttons[0].text = translations['de'].btn-confirm;` 
   `tempDialogParams.buttons[1].text = translations['de'].btn-decline;`
3. Destroy actual dialog 
   `dialog_appReset.destroy();`
4. Create new dialog 
   `dialog_appReset = app.dialog.create(tempDialogParams);`

Is that the only way to update the button text for an initialized dialog? Or is there a prettier way for that?

Note: I'm currently using [Framework7 v3](https://v3.framework7.io/docs/), but I can't find a way in v4 either.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the texts on an already opened dialog is anti patter IMHO. The dialog is meant to be the only thing the user can interact with, so the user shouldn't be able to change language while the dialog is opened, hence you don't need to update the button texts on the fly.

If this is a distributed system with many clients synchronized together and you need to reflect a change in the language setting made by a remote user, then let the client pick up the new language settings at the most convenient time (e.g. when no dialog box is shown on screen), you don't need to change it immediately no matter what.